# Javascript amelioration for option changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I guys,
I made a script which basically shows a different DIV box for each different radio button option check, starting with one default option already selected + the right div shown in the beginning.

Heres my jsfiddle for it:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E9mUf/)

I also use jQuery on my website. Any idea on how I could make the JS code cleaner, easier and simpler, in case I have more possible options (up to 10) ?

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
       $('#1').removeClass("hidden");
       $('#2').addClass("hidden");
       $('#3').addClass("hidden");
    }
if ($(this).val() == "2") {
       $('#1').addClass("hidden");
       $('#2').removeClass("hidden");
       $('#3').addClass("hidden");
    }
if ($(this).val() == "3") {
       $('#1').addClass("hidden");
       $('#2').addClass("hidden");
       $('#3').removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Please remember that the numbers that I use for the value="" will be a random number between 1 and 1000 (depending on the mysql database entry).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning that the div id will always be the value of the radio button?

Comment: This question would better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do something like this

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("div.euro").hide();
    $("#"+val).show();
});
```

On every div you should add the class 'euro'
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/E9mUf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
 /* your code upto now!
 if ($(this).val() == "1") {
   $('#1').removeClass("hidden");
   $('#2').addClass("hidden");
   $('#3').addClass("hidden");
 } */

 /* try this: */
 var val = $(this).val(); // get the value from the select element
 $('selector').addClass('hidden'); // add class to all!
 $('#' + val).removeClass('hidden'); // remove hidden class from the required
});
```

This way, you can run this code each time the change occurs, and depending on the value show or hide the content!

Please alter the value in the selector!

Answer (score 0):

Add `.hidden` to all of the divs, then remove the class based on the chosen value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='radio-269']").change(function() {
        $('div').addClass('hidden');
        $('div#'+this.value).removeClass('hidden');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `data-*` attribute using this code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" data-foo="10" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" data-foo="20" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="radio-269" data-foo="30" value="3" />
<div id="target">10 €</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[name='radio-269']").change(function () {
    $('#target').html($(this).data('foo') + ' €')
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rMYGQ/)**

Extending it to 10 options just means adding more inputs, no JavaScript changes needed: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FSPLh/)**